# Relative Layout disorganized at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

I have an issue with relative layout in my app. The problem is only in one activity and one fragment despite me using similar layouts in more than 20 other activities and fragments. In my xml design, the layout appears fine as follows.

[image]

However, at run-time, the layout design is messed up. Here is a screen shot of the layout during runtime.
[image]

Why am I having this problem?
Here is my layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/moments_toolbar_background"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_ollamoments_comment" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:gravity="left">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/settingsImageViewAccount"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_settings_moments_private"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/accountSettingsTextViewEditUsername"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Make profile private"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/settingsMoodTextColor"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settingsImageViewAccount"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchProfilePrivacy"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchProfilePrivacy" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchProfilePrivacy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:theme="@style/CustomSwitch"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@color/ollamoments_options_divider_color"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/settingsImageViewPhoneNumber"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_settings_moments_message"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Show my phone number on my public profile"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/settingsMoodTextColor"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settingsImageViewPhoneNumber"/>
<!--
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchMessages"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchMessages"-->

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchPhoneNumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:theme="@style/CustomSwitch"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@color/ollamoments_options_divider_color"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/settingsImageViewChats"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_settings_moments_message"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Allow people to message me"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/settingsMoodTextColor"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settingsImageViewChats"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchMessages"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchMessages" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchMessages"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:theme="@style/CustomSwitch"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@color/ollamoments_options_divider_color"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/settingsImageViewMoments"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_group"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Allow moments to be discoverable for trending"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/settingsMoodTextColor"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settingsImageViewMoments"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchDiscoverable"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchDiscoverable" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchDiscoverable"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:theme="@style/CustomSwitch"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@color/ollamoments_options_divider_color"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/settingsImageViewSupport"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_settings_moments_tagged"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Hide photos I'm tagged in"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/settingsMoodTextColor"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settingsImageViewSupport"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchHidePhotos"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchHidePhotos" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchHidePhotos"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:theme="@style/CustomSwitch"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@color/ollamoments_options_divider_color"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/settingsImageViewNotifications"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_settings_moments_location"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Show my location"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/settingsMoodTextColor"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settingsImageViewNotifications"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchLocation"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchLocation" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchLocation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:theme="@style/CustomSwitch"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@color/ollamoments_options_divider_color"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/settingsImageViewBlock"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_group"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Block users"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/settingsMoodTextColor"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settingsImageViewBlock" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@color/ollamoments_options_divider_color"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/settingsImageViewReccomendations"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_group"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Recommend people to follow"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/settingsMoodTextColor"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settingsImageViewReccomendations"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchRecommend"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchRecommend" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/momentSettingsSwitchRecommend"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:theme="@style/CustomSwitch"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@color/ollamoments_options_divider_color"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot align the TextView to the right of the ImageView AND to the left of the Switch.  You can only align it with one of the views.  Your preview shows it as left aligned but the phone shows it as right aligned.

My recommendation is to align the text with the ImageView and add a margin to the right side of the TextView roughly to the size of the Switch.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/accountSettingsTextViewEditUsername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Make profile private"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
    android:textColor="@color/settingsMoodTextColor"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settingsImageViewAccount"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp" />
```

Give that a try.  You may need to tweak the 48dp if you find that the text is running into the Switch.  You would obviously want to make a similar change for the other settingsMood textviews as well.